# Align text to bottom within A element

Tags: html, css

i'm having a menu consisting of clickable blocks. Its plain `ul/li/a` hierarchy spit out by Joomla.

I like to have the full blocks clickable and the text vertically aligned to the `bottom`, wanting both seems to be the problem here.

**HTML:**

```
<div>
    <ul>
        <li><a>Klinisch onderzoek</a></li>
        <li><a>Geneesmiddel- registratie</a></li>
        <li><a>Medische hulpmiddelen</a></li>
        <li><a>Orthopedie</a></li>
        <li><a>Leesbaarheids- test</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
ul li {
    list-style-type: none;
    float: left;
    margin: 0 0 15px 15px;
    background-color: #BA2876;
}
ul li a {
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 130px;
    width: 130px;
}
ul li a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}
```

See my Fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/jt7h5239/2/)

Comment: How about this - https://jsfiddle.net/jt7h5239/6/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Instead of setting the anchors to display:block, you could set them to table-cell, and then set the vertical alignment:

```
ul li a {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align:bottom;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 18px;
    padding: 10px;
    height: 130px;
    width: 130px;
}
```

**[jsFiddle example](https://jsfiddle.net/j08691/jt7h5239/5/)**

Answer (score 1):

You can use `display: table-cell` and `vertical-align: bottom`.

Example below:

```css
ul li {
  list-style-type: none;
  float: left;
  margin: 0 0 15px 15px;
  background-color: #BA2876;
  }

ul li a {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  color: #fff;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 18px;
  padding: 10px;
  height: 130px;
  width: 130px;
  }

ul li a:hover {
 text-decoration: underline;
  }
```

```html
<div>
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a>Klinisch onderzoek</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>Geneesmiddel- registratie</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>Medische hulpmiddelen</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>Orthopedie</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a>Leesbaarheids- test</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Oops, I forgot the clickable thing, I'm looking for it. Edit : If you had your hrefs it works.